# MSSQL Select more Tables to INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I'm struggling with this piece of code:

```
INSERT INTO Bier(Bier, BrowuerID, TypeID, GistingID, KleurID, Alcohol)
SELECT bb.Naam, b.BrouwerID, t.TypeID, g.GistingID, k.KleurID, bb.Alcoholperc
FROM BELGISCHBIER AS bb JOIN Brouwer AS b JOIN Type AS t JOIN Gisting AS g JOIN Kleur AS k
```

Can someone tell why this won't work because I don't really know that much about SQL

Thanks.

Comment: Because you forgot the `ON` clauses in your joins

Comment: IT Gives an error on line 3 by the JOIN

Comment: Syntax error is there

Comment: Juergen d i dont understand thos "ON"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `JOINS` without the mandatory `ON` clause which determines on what columns the tables should be joined:

```
INSERT INTO bier 
            ( 
                        bier, 
                        browuerid, 
                        typeid, 
                        gistingid, 
                        kleurid, 
                        alcohol 
            ) 
SELECT bb.naam, 
       b.brouwerid, 
       t.typeid, 
       g.gistingid, 
       k.kleurid, 
       bb.alcoholperc 
FROM   belgischbier AS bb 
JOIN   brouwer      AS b 
    ON bb.browuerid= b.browuerid
JOIN   type         AS t 
    ON b.BrouwerTypeID = t.BrouwerTypeID
JOIN   gisting      AS g 
    ON bb.GistingID = g.GistingID
JOIN   kleur        AS k
    ON g.KleurID = k.KleurID
```

Answer (score 0):

with `JOIN`, SQL understand `INNER JOIN`. So is mandatory use of `ON` clause.

Only if you use `CROSS JOIN` you can don't write `ON` clause.

So, add `ON` clause in your `JOIN` command.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some syntatical error , You missed the On clause In Join operation

try somethink like this,

```
INSERT INTO Bier(Bier, BrowuerID, TypeID, GistingID, KleurID, Alcohol)
SELECT bb.Naam, b.BrouwerID, t.TypeID, g.GistingID, k.KleurID, bb.Alcoholperc
FROM BELGISCHBIER AS bb <on Clause>JOIN Brouwer  AS b  <on Clause> JOIN Type on  AS t <on Clause> JOIN Gisting AS g  <on Clause>  JOIN  Kleur AS k  <on Clause>
```

Or simply you can use Cross Join ,it will not need On clause.

Syntax :

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
CROSS JOIN table2;
```

Example :

```
INSERT INTO Bier
            (Bier,BrowuerID,TypeID,GistingID,
             KleurID,Alcohol)
SELECT bb.Naam,b.BrouwerID,t.TypeID,g.GistingID,
       k.KleurID,bb.Alcoholperc
FROM   BELGISCHBIER AS bb
       CROSS JOIN Brouwer AS b
       CROSS JOIN Type AS t
       CROSS JOIN Gisting AS g
       CROSS JOIN Kleur AS k
```

Comment: what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have common columns between the tables use `Cross Join` else as mentioned by others you need to use `ON` condition to Join two tables

```
INSERT INTO Bier
            (Bier,BrowuerID,TypeID,GistingID,
             KleurID,Alcohol)
SELECT bb.Naam,b.BrouwerID,t.TypeID,g.GistingID,
       k.KleurID,bb.Alcoholperc
FROM   BELGISCHBIER AS bb
       CROSS JOIN Brouwer AS b
       CROSS JOIN Type AS t
       CROSS JOIN Gisting AS g
       CROSS JOIN Kleur AS k
```